# Displaying a sequence of images with a time delay

Tags: android

I wanted to display 9 images one after the other. I have included the 9 images as an array:

```
imageHolders = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    imageHolders.add((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgOne));
    imageHolders.add((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgTwo));
    imageHolders.add((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgThree));
    imageHolders.add((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgFour));
    imageHolders.add((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgFive));
    imageHolders.add((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgSix));
    imageHolders.add((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgSeven));
    imageHolders.add((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgEight));
    imageHolders.add((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgNine));
```

This is what I have tried:

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int currentImage = 0;
        int nextImage = 0;
        // Logic to change the images
        for (final ImageView imageView : imageHolders) {
            currentImage = Integer.parseInt(imageView.getTag().toString());
            if (currentImage > 1) {
                nextImage = currentImage - 1;
            } else {
                nextImage = 9;
            }
                     imageView.setTag(""+nextImage);

            new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                 }

                 public void onFinish() {
                        imageView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                 }
              }.start();        

        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }

}
```

There is a delay between the first and the second images. I am not able to introduce a delay between the rest. I have no clue about introducing the delay. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: why not just use AnimationDrawable which does this for you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html  ?

Comment: @MonaCheikhna : I think you could post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just use [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) which does this for you , and allows you to set a duration  of time (in milliseconds) using android:duration attribute .

Comment: animation drawable is not at all usefull in android. they always ends up with outof memory

Answer (score 1):

The AnimationDrawable is probably the best answer, but for another solution you can look at AsyncTask.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Then, you can in the background just sleep for some set amount of time, then display the next image.

You may want an event though to handle when this task is done, and in the listener you call the next one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make just a simple static animation (all images at the same position) you can use AnimationDrawable but you can't easly change it dynamically - like change speed or something.
I just wrote a simple class for this so I can set multiple animations for one ImageView and change speed.

```
public class ImageSequence extends ImageView {

ArrayList<Drawable> draws = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
ArrayList<Integer> bnds = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //bounds of sequences - index of first and last frame.
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(); //sequences names.
Timer timer = new Timer(true);
TimerTask task;
int p = -1; //current playback position.
int cS = -1; //current sequence.


public ImageSequence(Context context) {
    super(context);
    createTask();
}

public void addSequence(String name, int[] res){
    names.add(name);
    bnds.add(draws.size());
    bnds.add(draws.size() + res.length - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
        draws.add(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(res[i]));
    }
}

public void play(String sequence, float speed){     
    cS = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++){
        if(names.get(i) == sequence){ cS = i; break;}
    }
    if(cS<0) return;
    p = -1;
    task.run();
    task.cancel();
    if(speed <= 0) return;
    createTask();
    timer.schedule(task, (long) (1000/speed), (long) (1000/speed));
}

public void stop(){
    task.cancel();
}

public void cancelTimer(){
    timer.cancel();
}

private void createTask() {
    task = new TimerTask(){
        public void run() {
            p++;
            mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
        }
    };
}

public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int l = p;
        if(l > bnds.get(cS*2+1) || l < bnds.get(cS*2)) l = bnds.get(cS*2);
        p = l;
        ImageSequence.this.setImageDrawable(draws.get(l));
    }
};
}
```

From outside you can use it like this:

```
seq.addSequence("orange", new int[]{R.drawable.ic_oval_diode_orange, R.drawable.ic_oval_diode_off});
seq.addSequence("green", new int[]{R.drawable.ic_oval_diode_green, R.drawable.ic_oval_diode_off});
seq.addSequence("red", new int[]{R.drawable.ic_oval_diode_red, R.drawable.ic_oval_diode_off});
seq.play("red", 4);
```

I'm not really experienced in Android and Java but it works and it do the job for me. Hope it will help someone.